# Laravel check if user is authenticated regardless of guard

Tags: laravel, authentication

I have multiple guards for my site e.g.:

```
  'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
  ],

 'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],


    'recruiter' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
 ],
```

Is there a method to check if a user is simply signed in i.e. authenticated regardless of any guards?

Currently I have to do something like this:

```
if (Auth::guard('web')->check() || 
    Auth::guard('recruiter')->check() || 
    Auth::guard('admin')->check()) {

}
```

Comment: Guards define *how* a user is authenticated - think "API token versus session". They shouldn't be used for role management like this, IMO. A proper roles/permissions system like https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission would be better suited.

Comment: @ceejayoz this is to implement a google captcha on some forms and nothing more. If user is signed into application then no need to display captcha. The purpose of captcha is simply to determine you're not a bot. It doesn't matter if you are signed in as web or recruiter in above example. As long as you are signed in then that is enough confirmation you're not a bot.

Comment: @adam78 I think you misunderstood @ceejayoz's comment. Both recruiters and admins should sign in through the web guard then have roles to determine if they are a recruiter/admin or whatever. That way you can just check if they're logged in with `Auth::check()` to determine if they need a captcha. Then use roles elsewhere to check their permissions after they're logged in. In short, it appears you're using guards for something they are not designed to do, and that is the core of your problem here. Gaurds are for authentication (who are you), not authorization (what are you allowed to do).

Comment: @jfadich so maybe i'm using multiauth incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a single method for checking against all guards. Have you considered a middleware which encapsulates your auth guard checks so that at least then you don't have the checks peppered throughout your code base?

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated this isn't a feature provided by Laravel. You will probably have to create something in user land code for this feature. I've created something that might work for your specific use case:

```
namespace Your\Namespace;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Guard
{
    public static function checkAny(...$guards)
    {
        foreach($guards as $guard) {
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}

if (\Your\Namespace\Guard::checkAny('web', 'admin','recruiter')) {
    // don't show captcha
}
```